# When is a surjective hom a retraction?

Tags: category-theory, smooth-manifolds, quotient-group

Since I'm working in the niche category of $C^\infty$-rings, I'll state my question in general terms, though if you know more about this category, feel free to give a more specific answer.

I'm given an surjective hom $r:A\to B$, where $A$ is a quotient of a free object. I want to show that $r$ is a retraction. My first thought is that we can view $B=F/J$ as a quotient of the same free object $F$ and define an inverse on said free object. Then what remains to be shown is, that the kernel of this morphism is containing $J$. Here I fall flat. I am happy about any new thoughts or general ideas and feedback

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you using hom as short for homomorphism?

Comment: In many categories, this is impossible unless $B$ is free, in which case it's guaranteed. I am not sure whether a subobject of a free $C^\infty$-ring is free, though, so perhaps it's nontrivially possible in this setting.